# Blank page when I run ReactJS build on Apache server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache

[image][image]I try to figure out a way to display a test page. But there is no success until now. The way I have tried is with `npm run build`. I have created a `.htaccess` file , but still it returns me a blank page (without any errors in the console). Also i have inserted in my `package.json` the props `"homepage": "localhost/build-interface",` Anyone have some ideas how to fix the problem?

`index.js`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="localhost/build-interface/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="localhost/build-interface/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="localhost/build-interface/static/css/2.df50b353.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="localhost/build-interface/static/css/main.f68e1149.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <p>test here</p>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>!function (f) { function e(e) { for (var r, t, n = e[0], o = e[1], u = e[2], l = 0, i = []; l < n.length; l++)t = n[l], c[t] && i.push(c[t][0]), c[t] = 0; for (r in o) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, r) && (f[r] = o[r]); for (s && s(e); i.length;)i.shift()(); return p.push.apply(p, u || []), a() } function a() { for (var e, r = 0; r < p.length; r++) { for (var t = p[r], n = !0, o = 1; o < t.length; o++) { var u = t[o]; 0 !== c[u] && (n = !1) } n && (p.splice(r--, 1), e = l(l.s = t[0])) } return e } var t = {}, c = { 1: 0 }, p = []; function l(e) { if (t[e]) return t[e].exports; var r = t[e] = { i: e, l: !1, exports: {} }; return f[e].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, l), r.l = !0, r.exports } l.m = f, l.c = t, l.d = function (e, r, t) { l.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, { enumerable: !0, get: t }) }, l.r = function (e) { "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 }) }, l.t = function (r, e) { if (1 & e && (r = l(r)), 8 & e) return r; if (4 & e && "object" == typeof r && r && r.__esModule) return r; var t = Object.create(null); if (l.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: r }), 2 & e && "string" != typeof r) for (var n in r) l.d(t, n, function (e) { return r[e] }.bind(null, n)); return t }, l.n = function (e) { var r = e && e.__esModule ? function () { return e.default } : function () { return e }; return l.d(r, "a", r), r }, l.o = function (e, r) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r) }, l.p = "localhost/build-interface/"; var r = window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || [], n = r.push.bind(r); r.push = e, r = r.slice(); for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++)e(r[o]); var s = n; a() }([])</script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="localhost/build-interface/static/js/2.cd99b486.chunk.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="localhost/build-interface/static/js/main.eebb9fce.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should at least see `<p>test here</p>`. What happens when you view the source? Is it actually loading the HTML?

Comment: @FrankerZ i have updated my post with a pic of my inspector

Comment: It's not loading the javascript at all. Should it be `type="text/jsx"`?

Comment: @FrankerZ actually it's not a big difference if it is `type="text/jsx` or `type="text/javascript` . Actually i think that the problem is coming from my react-router-dom . Because on the static version when i change pages it doesn't change the path and instead of that stays on `localhost:3000`

Comment: But if you look at your network tab, it's not even trying to make a request for `localhost/build-interface/static/js/...`, so that's your problem right there. My guess is because your browser is ignore it, because it's an unknown script type.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/build-interface/static/js/2.a9289605.chunk.js"></script>` and
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="/build-interface/static/js/main.36459364.chunk.js"></script>`

These are my last changes that i have done and the result is here . 

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4bee0f2b6ba3c49e8049155bf30bc7b220190307124311/ed232cb17b1226c7b954db0306579e2e20190307124311/866774

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189597/discussion-between-pandamastr-and-frankerz).

Answer (score 0):

When you have a tag like this:

```
<script type="text/jsx" src="localhost/build-interface/static/js/2.cd99b486.chunk.js"></script>
```

It's not looking in `http://localhost`, it's actually looking in the folder `/localhost/...`. Prepend your script src with `//` to have it look in the correct folder (Or omit it entirely, and just use `/build-interface/...`). You would be able to see this in the network tab, as your scripts should be 404'ing.

Comment: My page does not load the script file . In the network is displayed only the `CSS` files with a status 200 . I tried with `//` and `http://localhost` and directly `/static/js/2.cd99b486.chunk.js.` but still there is a blank page with no result ...

Comment: i have updated the original post so you can see the result yourself .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my problem is similar to yours.

I was using the information from [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment) and [this](https://gist.github.com/santthosh/7dabf08fa3859361ef1e) one.

Using Chrome or Firefox inspect, the console informed that the CSS or JS files were using the wrong file type content (text/html). Searching google you will find many results informing that you just need to add to your .htacces:

```
AddType text/css .css
```

The problem was that my CSS and JS request were using the RewriteRule, meaning that my CSS and JS request, internally to apache, were returning index.html content.

I solved this issue including in the .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|txt)$ [NC]
```

The final .htaccess that I am using is:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . index.html [NC,QSA,L]
```